Avoid using specific characters in variable names generated by webpack
Background
I am developing small interactive snippets using React and MUI. These snippets are then bundled using Webpack (with a babel-loader). The resulting JS is then inserted as inline script into the HTML document, since I need one single chunk of HTML for these snippets.
In the productive environment, these chunks of HTML run through an Apache Velocity Engine (version 1.4) before it is presented to the client, this allows other snippet creators to use the Velocity Template Language.
My problem is that my Webpack and Babel setup generates JS that uses variable names like $i, which is interpreted by the Velocity Engine as Velocity variables. Some JS code is then interpreted as invalid Velocity syntax (like $i.bind(null,e[1])), which results in a Velocity error and the snippet not being rendered.
Question
Is there a way to avoid using the $ symbol in variable names generated by my pipeline? This way, nothing would be interpreted by the Velocity Engine and my JS could be safe.
Alternatively: How could I run the generated JS through a script, that replaces variable names, so I could for example replace all $i by Si or similar.
I already avoided template literals which are also critical in combination with the Velocity Engine
Setup
webpack.config.cjs
const HtmlBundlerPlugin = require("html-bundler-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            rootMode: 'upward',
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlBundlerPlugin({
      entry: "src/",
      entryFilter: /\.(html|eta|vtl)$/,
      test: /\.(html|eta|vtl)$/,
      filename: "[name][ext]",
      js: { inline: true },
      css: { inline: true }
    })
  ]
};

babel.config.json
{
  "targets": "defaults",
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "include": [
          "@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ]
}


please, create a small repo on GitHub with the reproducible problem and create an issue by the bundler plugin. I try to help you.
